# Delete a folder with file xy.z that is older then X days

Tags: cmd, forfiles

I want to delete all folders with an old file.
I try to solve it with forfiles to find my old files and remove the whole folder.
The problem i get is, when i found the file forfiles is in the folder what i want to delete and i get the "acess denied, is being used by another process" error.

```
forfiles /p "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\tmp\test" /s /m xy.z /d -1 /C "cmd /V:on /C  if @isdir==FALSE set tmpPath=@path&set tmpPath=!tmpPath:xy.z=!&cmd /c rd /s /q %tmpPath% "
```

Comment: To begin with, the initial command would probably be better written as, ```%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "%UserProfile%\Desktop\tmp\test" /S /M "xy.z" /D -1 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /V /C 0x22If @IsDir==FALSE Set 0x22tmpPath=@Path0x22 & RD /S /Q 0x22!tmpPath:~1,-6!0x220x22"```. There seems no need to perform a second `set` command, especially when you already know the string length of the matched filename. Also I'm not sure why you've decided to invoke another instance of cmd.exe to perform the `RD` command. If that was part of your attempted solution then use a `CD` in it.

Comment: Thx for your hints.
I'm not really proficient with cmd programming, so sometimes it's not the best way. I also tried to solve it with cd.. without success

Comment: Show us that code.

Comment: `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "%UserProfile%\Desktop\tmp\test" /S /M "xy.z" /D -1 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /V /C 0x22If @IsDir==FALSE Set 0x22tmpPath=@Path0x22 & cd.. & dir & RD /S /Q 0x22!tmpPath:~1,-6!0x220x22"`

dir only to see in which folder i am. I think the problem is, forfiles is the outer funktion and it is still in this folder, no matter what i am doing inside my cmd command